# Trying to replace a pattern match with "" using gsub

Tags: r, gsub

Here is a string:

```
x <- "[CAD]-Other"
```

I want to get rid of anything inside square braces so that

```
>x
"-Other"
```

I tried:

```
gsub("^\\[[^\\]]*\\]$", "", x)
[1] "[CAD]-Other"
```

I used regex101 to sanity check my regex and it does seem to work on that site:
https://regex101.com/r/Xl77pO/1

How can I replace anything contained within square braces in a string?

Comment: This specific case seems that it can be handled by `sub('.*-', '-', x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can match a square bracket (escaped -`\\[` as it is a metacharacter) followed by zero or more characters that are not a closing square bracket (`[^]]*`) followed by a closing square bracket (`\\]`), replace with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("\\[[^]]*\\]", "", x)
#[1] "-Other"
```

For this example, even `sub` is enough

```
sub("\\[[^]]*\\]", "", x)
#[1] "-Other"
```

Comment: Thanks. For my sanity, what is the double braces doing? `[[^]]` (just saw your edit! Will delete this comment shortly, thank you!)

Comment: @DougFir  The one inside the square brackets matches any character that is not (`^`) a  `]`

Comment: @DougFir the regex parses as `\\[` (literal left bracket) `[^]]*` (any characters that are not a right bracket) `\\]` (literal right bracket)

Comment: Interesting I don't have to escape the right bracket within the negation with hat ^, so don't have to `[^\\]]*`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(rebus)
library(stringr)

x <- "[CAD]-Other"

str_replace(x, pattern = START %R% "\\[" %R% one_or_more(WRD) %R% "]", "")
str_replace(x, pattern = "\\[" %R% one_or_more(WRD) %R% "]", "")
```